# A specific type of extrusion

Tags: modeling

My model is easy, a cube scaled from top (left image)

I want to extrude edge x, but willing the result like in the right image

Thank you for reading

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can:

- Duplicate the side face with a <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>D</kbd>
- Select the top edge and slide it with <kbd>G</kbd><kbd>G</kbd>, press <kbd>C</kbd> to extend:

[image]

- Only keep the top edge of this new face:

[image]

- Fill the face:

[image]

Comment: Well it is smart of you to use clipping while moving the edge instead of extruding, this is how i did it.my question is(since i know all 4 types of extruding): if I click 'e' to extrude is there any shortcut that does it while extruding is locked?

Comment: I don't know how you can make it work with extrusion, you could create a custom orientation from the face, but you won't have the reduction you show